# Getting ERROR while adding Name spaces in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am getting below error while using adding name spaces code.

I have added the namespaces code in the while loop.for the first iteration it is working fine.for the second iteration it is giving below error.

Error:

```
exception  class="oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDOMException">
invalid character : in name
<stack>
<f>oracle.xml.util.XMLUtil.validateQualifiedName#525</f>
<f>oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument.createElementNS#2705</f>
<f>oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument.otherImportNode#2350</f>
<f>oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument.importNode#2326</f>
<f>oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument.otherImportNode#2459</f>
<f>oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument.importNode#2326</f>
<f>com.collaxa.cube.xml.dom.DOMUtil.copyElement#558</f>
<f>com.collaxa.cube.xml.dom.DOMUtil.copyObjHelper#300</f>
```

I am using the  below adding Namesapces code inside the while loop.The while loop process multiple records for the first  iteration.It is  able to process.but for the second iteration it is giving error.

adding Namespaces code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:vbs="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<!-- Just change the match="/*" to match="*" ; if you want to add namespace in all elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="inp1:{local-name()}"  namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/sp/Call856OutboundProcedure1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What does your source XML look like? You say you're using a while loop. What does that look like?

Comment: If this is the real transformation you are using, it is working OK with the major XSLT processors (11 of them) I have. Maybe this is a bug in Oracle's XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided rather sparse information here, but I would suggest trying this approach (specifying the namespace uri in the stylesheet root instead of in the `<xsl:element>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:vbs="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
         xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
         xmlns:inp1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/sp/Call856OutboundProcedure1">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<!-- Just change the match="/*" to match="*" ; if you want to add namespace in all elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="inp1:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```